# Do I need to ground this circuit board inside my 3d printed case?

Tags: ground, grounding, circuit-protection

I bought a microphone amp system that has 2 mics and then outputs the audio via aux cable. I am using it for a project and 3d printed an enclosure for it and took out the circuit board from the microphone system. However I noticed the screws on it have conductive plates that go into the original enclosure which is some sort of metal.

Do I need to ground the board and how would I do it with a plastic case now?[image]

Comment: Which amp it was? Maybe put a link to it.

Comment: https://fifinemicrophone.com/products/wireless-microphone-system-for-karaoke-k036

Comment: I guess it isn't an amp just a receiver.

Comment: What does the data sheet of the product tell you to do?